# Align picture directly next to <h> tag

Tags: html, css

I started to learn HTML and CSS a few days ago and now got a problem:

```css
#referenzen{
        width: 100%;
        padding: 25px;
    
    }

    #referenzen h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    #referenzen p{
        padding-right: 25px;
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    #referenzen img{
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        float: left;
    }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="referenzen">
        <img src="../Bilder/info.png">
        <h1>Unsere Firmengeschichte</h1>
        <br>
        <p>Die Firma Fair-Bau GmbH wurde im April 2010 gegründet und betätigt sich in den Sparten ausführende Baumeisterarbeiten, Vollwärmeschutzarbeiten, Verputzarbeiten sowie dem Handel mit Baustoffen.
            Der Betrieb beschäftigt 15- 20 Mitarbeiter. </p>
    </div>
```

How can i directly assign the image to the  tag so that its directly next to it?

The page at it´s current state: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zq0gJ.jpg

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Non related to your question, but notice that is not the same `#referenzen h1, h2, h3` and `#referenzen h1, #referenzen h2, #referenzen h3`.

Comment: Could you please be more specific. Let us know if you just want to move the image down or something else.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could just `margin-top: 15px` to the image.

```css
#referenzen {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
}
#referenzen h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
#referenzen p {
  padding-right: 25px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
#referenzen img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="referenzen">
    <img src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/dccu/images/b/bc/Icon-Wikipedia.png/revision/latest?cb=20160324075444">
    <h1>Unsere Firmengeschichte</h1>
    <br>
    <p>Die Firma Fair-Bau GmbH wurde im April 2010 gegründet und betätigt sich in den Sparten ausführende Baumeisterarbeiten, Vollwärmeschutzarbeiten, Verputzarbeiten sowie dem Handel mit Baustoffen. Der Betrieb beschäftigt 15- 20 Mitarbeiter.</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I would do it:

- In HTML: You could insert the `<img>`-tag inside you `<h1></h1>`-tag
- in CSS: You could set `h1` and `img` to `display: inline-block`

I'd prefer the first one.

EDIT for better understanding:

The tags `<h1>...<h6>` have a default `display` of `block` which means they take a total of 100% width of the parent container.
So changing it to inline-block destroys the 100% width and shrinks it down to either a set width-value or if that isn't set to the size of the contained elements.